# How to resize the height of the HTML <object> tag dynamically to display all the content without showing the scrollbars

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to resize the **object** tag to be 100% the height of the rendered page. I have tried different ways to accomplish it still unable to do it. I mentioned below the few distinct ways which I attempted.

CSS

```
#container {
    display: flex;   
    flex-direction:column;  
    width:100%; 
}
#container object {      
     flex: 1;
}

*******************
 object {
     height : 100%;
     width : 100%;
     overflow : hidden;
 }
*********************
div#container {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
object {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

**********
```

HTML

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
   <head> 
      <meta charset="utf-8">
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="container">  
          <object id="obj" data="contactus.asp"  width="100%" type="text/html"></object> 
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Even I tried applying inline style in **object** tag and also height="100%" as well yet not able to resolve it.

I really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

```css
object {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<object>Test</object>
```

The object tag, is by default, inline, which will not allow you to change the size. You should change the display to inline-block or block first to allow for this. Now, you should change % to vw (viewport width) and vh (viewport height), because % is relative to the container (body). Finally, the body will have some margin that has to be removed with margin:0.

Comment: Thanks for the expedited response. Not able to resolved the issue completely. I have updated the question. Have a look at it and give your suggestion.